# Cloning autopopulated text fields from dropdown

Tags: php, combobox, clone

First off, complete newbee here.  I have been strugging with trying to clone a combobox.  Do I have the lingo right?  Essentially what I am trying to do is have a dropdown that populates several fields, and then hit an add button and do it all again.  I'm able to populate the first row of fields but nothing after cloning.  Help?  Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reCopy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';

$('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var compInfoArray = new Array();

    <?php
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bha_product ORDER BY product";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

        // build javascript array
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
            echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].'] = new Array();';
            echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["product"] = "'.$row1['product'].'";';
            echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["description"] = "'.$row1['description'].'";';
                        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["price"] = "'.$row1['price'].'";';
        }
    ?>

    function showname() {
        var productid = document.form1.productid.value;
        document.form1.product.value = compInfoArray[productid]["product"];
        document.form1.description.value = compInfoArray[productid]["description"];
        document.form1.price.value = compInfoArray[productid]["price"];
    }

    window.onload=function() {
        showname();
    } 

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">  
    <p class="clone">   
             <select name="productid" onchange="showname()">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bha_product ORDER BY product";
            $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

            // build javascript array
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row1['productid'].'">'.$row1['product'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="product" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="price" value="" />


        </label></p><p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a></p>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
    <br>    


    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Add" /> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant but it works.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
    ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reCopy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';

    $('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var compInfoArray = new Array();
        <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bha_product ORDER BY product";
            $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

            // build javascript array
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
                echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].'] = new Array();';
                echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["product"] = "'.$row1['product'].'";';
                echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["description"] = "'.$row1['description'].'";';
                echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['productid'].']["price"] = "'.$row1['price'].'";';
            }
        ?>

        function showname( place ) {
            var productid = $( place ).val();
            $( place ).next().children('input[name="product"]').val(compInfoArray[productid]["product"]);
            $( place ).next().children('input[name="description"]').val(compInfoArray[productid]["description"]);
            $( place ).next().children('input[name="price"]').val(compInfoArray[productid]["price"]);
        }
        var i = 1;
        function clone(){
            $(".exemple_for_clone").clone().removeClass("exemple_for_clone").addClass("clone" + (i + 1)).appendTo("#clone_input_place");
            i++;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1">
        <div style="display: none;">
            <p class="exemple_for_clone">   
                <select name="productid" onchange="showname(this)">
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                <?php
                    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bha_product ORDER BY product";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

                    // build javascript array
                    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
                        echo '<option value="'.$row1['productid'].'">' . $row1['product'] . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="product" value="" />
                    <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
                    <input type="text" name="price" value="" />
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="clone0">   
            <select name="productid" onchange="showname(this)">
            <option value="">Select Product</option>
            <?php
                $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bha_product ORDER BY product";
                $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

                // build javascript array
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row1['productid'].'">' . $row1['product'] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="product" value="" />
                <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
                <input type="text" name="price" value="" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p id="clone_input_place"></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone" onclick="clone()">Add More</a></p>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
        <br>    


        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Add" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response.  I'll try it out.  Last time I worked with any coding was back in the mid 90's.  God, I feel old.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because it isn't cloning and the first combobox isn't populating.

Comment: Any other way to go about doing this?  All I really need to do is clone new comboboxes, or at least direct me to a decent tutorial.  I've looked all over and can't find a darn thing.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/usamed/1/ - Please look at this example. This is something that you need or I did not understand your request correctly?

Comment: I obviously screwed something up.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked.  I don't know what I was doing wrong when I tried it before.  Senior moment I guess.

Comment: Maybe you don't include jquery? I rewrite example with your php code. Try it now.

Comment: "I tried your code and it worked." Oh, in this case it all alright =)

Comment: Now I seem to be having an issue trying to get a php query going.  Not entirely sure about this, again, I'm relearning everything.  Thanks again.